# How to get http response content of Slim PHP Api with Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I have an API programmed with Slim PHP which sends JSON responses like this:

```
$response['some-text'] = 'blabla';
$app->response->setStatus(200);
$app->response()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Now when I open an API url in a browser, the message is displayed as wanted. However, if I open the same url with my ionic app using angular JS like this:

```
$http.get("URL").success(function(response) {console.log(response)});
```

when I check the console afterwards, I only see the code (200) but no JSON with the message. However, I'm sure that the API did receive the call correctly, as actions like adding items to a database are executed just fine. But how can I get the response?

/edit
Here is a screenshot from the console, what the empty response looks like

header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Zt6.jpg

answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbv0J.jpg

Comment: dont use `.success` use `.then`. `.success` is depreciated.

Comment: Is api  on same domain, protocol and port as page making request?

Comment: try printing something specific from the response like `response.data.id` when you make the request, that will show you if its coming in correctly. use your own JSON though obviously

Comment: @joe changed that, but did not help

Comment: what does your json actually look like?

Comment: @charlie api and page called are on the same server, but i do not know any more details. can you clarify what you think might be the problem?

Comment: @joe for example: {"success":true,"message":"User 123 successfully created"}

Comment: try `console.log(reponse.message[0])` and see if it prints your first message

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. While I'm not sure it is a good one, it certainly works.

I added this code to my response function in php:

```
$app->response()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$app->response()->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET'); //or whatever you need
$app->response()->headers->set('AAccess-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
```

which, if you don't use slim php, should be equal to:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```